# Limit of two convergent sequences of complex numbers equals the limit of the arithmetical sum of their inverse productory

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Down below I leave my question. It's pretty much self explaining.

Let $(z_{n})_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ and $(w_{n})_{n}^{+\infty}$ convergent sequences of complex numbers. Prove that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{z_{0}w_{n}+z_{1}w_{n-1}+\dots+z_{n}w_{0}}{n+1} =(\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty}z_{k})(\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty}w_{m})
\end{equation*}

What i have got so far:

I have recognized that
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_{0}w_{n}+z_{1}w_{n-1}+\dots+z_{n}w_{0}}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}(z_{i}w_{n-i}))
\end{align*}
I am kind of stuck on here right now. I have tried to split the limit (using the product propertie) to try and use the following result:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{z_{0}+z_{1}+\dots+z_{n-1}}{n} = \lim_{k}z_{k},
\end{align*}
for any $(z_{n})_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ convergent sequence of complex numbers.

If i could prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(z_{i}w_{n-i})$ can be adapted to be written as $v_{0}+v_{1}+\dots+v_{n}$ and that $\lim_{n}v_{n} = (\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty}z_{k})(\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty}w_{m})$ the exercise would become a lot more easier.
I wasn't able to do that, if anyone could help me with this one i would be really thankfull. Have a nice one guys.

Comment: Did not you confuse $\sum$ and $\prod$ notation?

Comment: Yes, my bad! Already edited it, now it's correct i think. Thanks for the correction

Comment: My first thought is to adapt the proof of the Cesaro summation identity you listed, which is the $w_i = 1$ for all $i$ special case. I'd guess the point of the exercise is to get you to understand the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is going to be a $\delta-\epsilon$ version of this informal argument:

Let $Z = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} z_n$ and $W = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} w_n$

Take $M$ such that for all $m \geq N$, $z_m$ is close to $Z$ and $w_m$ is close to $W$. Then for sufficiently large $m$, we throw away the terms $\frac{z_0 w_m + ... + z_N w_{m - N}}{m + 1}$ and $\frac{z_{m - N} w_N + ... + z_m w_0}{m + 1}$, since these terms will be approximately $W \frac{z_0 + z_1 + ... + z_n}{m + 1}$ and $Z \frac{w_0 + w_1 + ... + w_n}{m + 1}$ respectively, which both clearly are small when $m$ is large.

The middle term will be a sum of $m + 1 - 2N$ terms of the form $z_a w_b$ where $a, b \geq N$, divided by $m + 1$. It will thus be approximately $\frac{(m + 1 - 2N) W Z}{m + 1}$, which will be close to $WZ$.

Comment: Hello Mark, I fully agree with your proof until the last part of it, when you say that the middle term will be a sum of terms assuming the form $z_{a}w_{b}$, where a,b >= N. In fact, the middle term will assume the form $z_{a}w_{b}$ but a,b < N, in my calculations. I feel like im doing something wrong here, if you could explicit the reason why those terms are >= N i would be really thankfull.

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues Let's take the special case of $N = 2$ and $m = 5$. Then the numerator will be $z_0 w_5 + z_1 w_4 + z_2 w_3 + z_3 w_2 + z_4 w_1 + z_5 w_0$. The "middle terms" will be $z_2 w_3 + z_3 w_2$. Each of the subscripts there is $\geq N = 2$.

Comment: I believe that, in that specific case, there would be no middle terms since the numerator could be aproximated as $W(z_{0}+z_{1}) + Z\(w_{0}+w_{1})$. Taking, for example, N = 4 and m = 5 the numerator would be: $z_{0}w_{5} + z_{1}w_{4} + z_{2}w_{3} + z_{3}w_{2} + z_{4}w_{1} + z_{5}w_{0}$. In this case, the middle terms would be $z_{2}w_{3} + z_{3}w_{2}$  and $2,3 \leq 4$. I don't know if im just confused or not understanding, but thanks for your answers and your time!